# How to display the total number of places in Google Maps and Drupal-7 views?

Tags: google-maps, drupal, drupal-7, maps

I have to display the total number of canteens in a particular region.

For example: in city A there are 10 canteens. I have to display an icon with the number 10. After clicking that icon it will display exact locations of the canteens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Gmap3 and Clustering, you can have custom icons for clusters and the total count is set within the icon. By default clicking zooms in to open the cluster, although you can add custom events.

See http://gmap3.net/examples/clustering.html